# FileNotFound exception while trying to load infinispan configuration file

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, hibernate-search, infinispan

I am trying to configure infinispan with Hibernate Search. It's working fine with default configuration, but I need to use a Cache Manager with it and therefore need to configure infinispan configuration file as:

```
hibernate.search.infinispan.configuration_resourcename=infinispan.xml
```

But it's giving FileNotFound exception as follows:

```
caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Could not start Infinispan CacheManager using as configuration file: infinispan.xml
    at org.hibernate.search.infinispan.CacheManagerServiceProvider.start(CacheManagerServiceProvider.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.StandardServiceManager$ServiceProviderWrapper.startVirtual(StandardServiceManager.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.StandardServiceManager.requestService(StandardServiceManager.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.search.infinispan.impl.InfinispanDirectoryProvider.initialize(InfinispanDirectoryProvider.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:88)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: infinispan.xml
    at org.hibernate.search.infinispan.impl.InfinispanConfigurationParser.parseFile(InfinispanConfigurationParser.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.search.infinispan.CacheManagerServiceProvider.start(CacheManagerServiceProvider.java:96)
    ... 78 more
```

Can someone guide me if they have any idea about configuring infinispan cache manager with hibernate search.

Comment: probably your configuration file is not in the correct place

Comment: It's in the classpath. Can you suggest which location would be correct? I am little lost here.

Comment: Could you clarify which version of Hibernate Search, Infinispan, etc.. and if you're running in a container?

Comment: @Sanne I kept the file in `src\main\resources\infi\` folder and in the war it was not included in classes folder. Later in moved it to `src\main\resources` and it worked.

Comment: Shall, I marked this question as answered or it was a silly mistake and I should delete this question at all?

Comment: @Sanne If possible, Can you have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502021/how-to-configure-amazon-s3-as-remote-cache-store-for-hibernate-search?noredirect=1#comment84006405_48502021 this question. I am stuck here.

Comment: I see you figured it out, but the question is still open. I've re-elaborated our comments into an answer, please accept it so this doesn't look unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `hibernate.search.infinispan.configuration_resourcename` is meant to open a configuration *resource* so it must be on your classpath or included as a resource in your project.

Also remember that the value is interpreted as an *absolute* path to the resource, so if you have

```
hibernate.search.infinispan.configuration_resourcename=infinispan.xml
```

Then the `infinispan.xml` resource should be in the root folder of your project resources.

Comment: Well explained. Thanks