# How to configure Amazon S3 as remote cache store for Hibernate Search 4.5.3

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-s3, hibernate-search, infinispan

I have configured Hibernate Search to use infinispan and use File System based Cache Store to persist the indexes in file system instead of memory.

Now, I wish to configure S3 instead of File System, but I am not able to find the correct configuration for this.

My infinispan.xml file is:

```
<infinispan
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:6.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-6.0.xsd"
      xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:6.0">

  <global>
    <globalJmxStatistics enabled="false" />
    <!-- <transport clusterName="storage-test-cluster" /> -->
    <shutdown hookBehavior="DONT_REGISTER" />
  </global>

  <default>
    <storeAsBinary
      enabled="false" />
    <locking
      isolationLevel="READ_COMMITTED"
      lockAcquisitionTimeout="20000"
      writeSkewCheck="false"
      concurrencyLevel="5000"
      useLockStriping="false" />
    <invocationBatching
      enabled="false" />
  </default>

  <namedCache name="LuceneIndexesMetadata">
    <persistence passivation="false">
       <singleFile
         fetchPersistentState="true"
         preload="true"
         purgeOnStartup="false"
         shared="true"
         ignoreModifications="false"
         location="C:\\infinispan">
       </singleFile>
     </persistence>
  </namedCache>

  <namedCache name="LuceneIndexesData">
    <persistence passivation="false">
       <singleFile
         fetchPersistentState="true"
         preload="true"
         purgeOnStartup="false"
         shared="true"
         ignoreModifications="false"
         location="C:\\infinispan">
       </singleFile>
     </persistence>
  </namedCache>

  <namedCache name="LuceneIndexesLocking">
    <!-- No CacheLoader configured here -->
  </namedCache>

</infinispan>
```

Can anyone help me in configuring this file to use Amazon S3 as Cache Store.

Comment: What Infinispan version?

Comment: I am using Hibernate Search 4.5.3 which bundles Infinispan 6.0

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not aware of any examples for that Infinispan version. The earliest version for which we seem to have integration is Infinispan 8.

Comment: Actually, I remember what happened now. We used to have an S3 cloud cache store for Infinispan before Infinispan 5. Then in 6 we changed the cache store API and we didn't migrate the S3 cloud cache store until Infinispan 8.

Comment: Thanks @GalderZamarreño. Well explained

Comment: There will soon be a release of the Cloud Cache Store for Infinispan 9.x which will include examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific versions of Hibernate Search and Infinispan which you're using are extremely old. Specifically, Infinispan didn't support storage on Amazon S3 in version 6.

I would suggest upgrading to some more recent version which is still being maintained.

As of writing this, you could use *Infinispan 9.1.5.Final* with *Hibernate Search 5.8.2.Final*.